# ethereum user friendly app

Tags: dapp-design

I'm designing a new business with blockchain technology. And I would like to create a very user friendly app. I do not want to force people to have a wallet and ethers to interact with blockchain.

So I designed a process to interact on the blockchain with user friendly approach.

Steps : - a user create an account on an application - once logged the user do an action and want communicate with blockchain - the application will estimate the amount of gas to make the transaction on Ethereum - the application will convert ethers amount on eur - the application will ask the user to pay with credit card - when the application received payment, the application will use its own wallet to sign and send the transaction - once the transaction has been mined and validated, the application will store the transaction receipt on database

I would like to know if this model is correct, feasible and interesting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think if you did it that way, it basically negates the entire point of using Ethereum. At that point, it's better to either do a traditional application or use a sidechain.